# volatile was removed and now had no effect use with.torch.no_grad() instread

Tags: pytorch

my torch program stopped at this point 
I guess i can not use volatile=True

how should I change it and what is the reason to stop?

 and How should I change this code?

```
images = Variable(images.cuda())
targets = [Variable(ann.cuda(), volatile=True) for ann in targets]
```

> train.py:166: UserWarning: volatile was removed and now has no effect.
>   Use `with torch.no_grad():` instead.

Answer (score 5):

`Variable` doesn't do anything and has been deprecated since pytorch 0.4.0. Its functionality was merged with the `torch.Tensor` class. Back then the `volatile` flag was used to disable the construction of the computation graph for any operation which the volatile variable was involved in. Newer pytorch has changed this behavior to instead use `with torch.no_grad():` to disable construction of the computation graph for anything in the body of the `with` statement.

What you should change will depend on your reason for using volatile in the first place. No matter what though you probably want to use

```py
images = images.cuda()
targets = [ann.cuda() for ann in targets]
```

During training you would use something like the following so that the computation graph is created (assuming standard variable names for model, criterion, and optimizer).

```py
output = model(images)
loss = criterion(images, targets)
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

Since you don't need to perform backpropagation during evaluation you would use `with torch.no_grad():` to disable the creation of the computation graph which reduces the memory footprint and speeds up computation.

```py
with torch.no_grad():
    output = model(images)
    loss = criterion(images, targets)
```