# Volatile was removed and now has no effect. Use `with torch.no_grad():` instead

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, torchvision, mscoco

I tried to using Show And Tell model with COCO dataset. But, at one point my Torch program paused. Can anyone fix my code? Here is my code which causes the training to pause.

```
def to_var(x, volatile=True):
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    x = x.cuda()
return Variable(x, volatile=volatile)
```

And the warning was below.

> utils.py:114: UserWarning: volatile was removed and now has no effect. Use with torch.no_grad(): instead. return Variable(x, volatile=volatile)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [volatile was removed and now had no effect use with.torch.no\_grad() instread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61720460/volatile-was-removed-and-now-had-no-effect-use-with-torch-no-grad-instread)

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of Pytorch `volatile` is removed and also `Variable` is not necessary.
Any computation of a tensor with `volatile=True` wouldn’t be tracked by `autograd`.
So your function can be rewritten as:

```
import torch
def to_var(x, volatile=True):
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        x = x.cuda()
    x.requires_grad = not volatile
    return x

x = torch.tensor(1.0)
print(x.requires_grad)
x = to_var(x, volatile=True)
print(x.requires_grad)
x = to_var(x, volatile=False)
print(x.requires_grad)
```

Output:

```
>>> False
>>> False
>>> True
```