# volatile was removed and now has no effect. Use `with torch.no_grad():` instead. inputs_Var = Variable(inputs, volatile=True)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pip, pytorch, google-colaboratory

```
from torch.autograd import Variable


def test(testloader, net, index, epoch, use_cuda, logger):
    losses = AverageMeter()

net.eval()

for batch_idx, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(testloader):
    if use_cuda:
        inputs = inputs.cuda()

    inputs_Var = Variable(inputs, volatile=True)
    outputs = net(inputs_Var, index)

    # measure accuracy and record loss
    losses.update(outputs.item(), inputs.size(0))
```

==> UserWarning: volatile was removed and now has no effect. Use `with torch.no_grad():` instead.
inputs_Var = Variable(inputs, volatile=True)

Use

```
with torch.no_grad():
    inputs_Var = Variable(inputs, volatile=True)
    outputs = net(inputs_Var, index)
```

but ==> UserWarning: volatile was removed and now has no effect. Use `with torch.no_grad():` instead. inputs_Var = Variable(inputs, volatile=True)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61720460/volatile-was-removed-and-now-had-no-effect-use-with-torch-no-grad-instread

Comment: Voting to close as it seems to be a duplicate of ^

Comment: Don't use `Variable` altogether.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Don't use volatile or Variable. Just use `outputs = net(inputs, index)` within the `torch.no_grad()` context and delete the line that assigned `inputs_Var`.

Comment: many thank you much, its worked